# How does WordPress handle global variables that are specific to sessions and not overridden by concurrent users?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I'm looking in core for where the global $post object is being initially set but I'm not sure where or where the logic would be that would handle concurrent users. I'm assuming this creates multiple global $post objects for various requests and perhaps tie that to some $_SESSION variable.

I'm trying to understand how WordPress gets away with using global variables in its application and being able to scale.

Comment: This isn't so much a WordPress thing, as the way [PHP is designed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435959/reading-and-writing-global-variables-across-scripts-in-php), and what "global" actually means in the language.

Comment: that's because they are different than the $_SESSION variables. You should look for the PHP concept for Global. Doesn't have to do with WordPress.